# WebView Failure

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have created a WebView of this website https://smartfix.pk/ but in my app, WhatsApp is not working,
when I click it gives me the error

[image]

> webpage at whatsapp://send/?phone=923005475032&text=Hello%2C%20I%20have%20a%20question%20about%20SmartFix%20Services could not be loaded because: net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        web.loadUrl("https://smartfix.pk/");
    }


    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent(WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: You are exposing your personal numbers here.. Please blur it out before posting it in SO

Comment: There is no issue in your webpage. Actually you've to change your website. Which framework and language you've used for website? I've done such work in Laravel php.

Comment: @MuhammadFarhanArif Website is developed in Laravel PHP.
Now tell me how I can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this, i'm not sure it's will work for that page but when i'm using webview i always enable all to be sure

```
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, tried this also but still not solved.

Comment: @SyedShahrose then check it's link entered ok